# If a set $S$ has a proper subset $A$ that is infinite, then $S$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through Herstein's Algebra and I have become stuck on a seemingly simple exercise.

I am using the definition that a set S is said to be infinite if there exists a bijection between $S$ and a proper subset of $S$.

The concept of Cardinality has not been introduced yet.

Intuition tells me that this statement is true, but I am getting hung up on the details. This is what I have so far:

Proof: Let the set $S$ contain a proper subset $A$ such that $A$ is infinite. Then there is exists a proper subset of $A$, which we will denote $B$, such that there exists a bijection $f$ between $A$ and $B$. (I would know like to show that this bijection necessarily implies a bijection between $S$ and $B$) This is where I am getting hung up. Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way?

Comment: Define your bijection using $f$ on $A$, but some other formula outside $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but possibly overthinking it: You cannot expect to have a bijection $S\to B$ (in fact, $B$ might be too small if it is "just" countably infinite and $S$ is not).
Instead let $T=(S\setminus A)\cup B$ and define $g\colon S\to T$ by

$$ g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }x\in A\\x&\text{if }x\notin A\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

You started okay, but continued less okay.

It's not necessarily the case that $S$ and $B$ have a bijection between them. But what can you say about $S$ and $B\cup(S\setminus A)$? Can you extend, perhaps, your given bijection $f\colon A\to B$ to be a bijection between those sets?